# Can you batch delete in REDCap?

Tags: redcap

We recently had a duplication in uploaded records to one of our REDCap projects totaling about 3,800 files that now need to be removed. Currently it is taking a team of three about 30 seconds per record to delete due to the size of the project and traffic in REDCap. I have not found any solution to delete multiple records at once from Vanderbilt or the other university resources I typically use. I was wondering if others have found a work around?

Answer (score 2):

There is an API method for deleting records, so that would be your best bet for batch deletion. The details, with examples for different languages, are in the API and API playground applications in the project sidebar. You must have an API token generated, and your admin might have to approve that before you can use the API. It also inherits your privileges on the project, so you need to have the privilege to delete records in the User Rights application.

Another method that might be easier and cleaner would be to ditch this particular project and copy the project without its records, then perform the import on the new, empty project.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`REDCapR::redcap_delete()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_delete.html) if you're using R, or PyCap's [`delete_records()`](http://redcap-tools.github.io/PyCap/api_reference/records/#redcap.methods.records.Records.delete_records) if you're using Python.

Packages for other languages are listed in [REDCap Tools](https://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/).

Answer (score 0):

Put the project back into Development Mode, then put it back into Production Mode and choose the option to delete all records.

Comment: Does this solution delete all records or only the duplicated ones?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes upon this. Another method is to do an export and import of records and fields using the steps below. Not the cleanest but can be the safest. Make sure to do a backup of the project and/or exported document so you can restore it if a mistake is made. Also consider using a new or test project to make sure the below works as expected for you.

1. Export all records and fields using the Reports tool.
2. Remove the records that you want to delete from the project from the spreadsheet.
3. (optional) You can keep the existing record_id or renumber them in the spreadsheet if you'd like.
4. Use Project Home -> Other Functionality -> Erase all data (Make SURE you are either working on a separate project or downloaded ALL data first!!)
5. Reimport the spreadsheet using the "Data Import Tool" left sidebar.

Data should now be loaded minus the deleted data. Record ID's will either be the original, or newly assigned ones depending on what you did for Step 3. The upload may take a while.

Hope this helps anyone searching for a bulk delete solution.